# Remove command from auto-completion / history

Tags: windows, command-line

In windows command prompt, say we are running a command (batch file)

```
runtest
```

but we typo as

```
runtet
```

Then when we press F8 next time at 'run',it will still pop with 'runtet'.

Is there any way to remove this incorrect command from auto completion list without restarting the cmd prompt? Or a better way to achieve this?

Without restarting because, there are other commands which are relevant for auto completion and also the environment (though it can be set by batch file).

Answer (score 1):

Certainly is.

Try pressing `up-arrow` rather than `F8` to return to previous lines. You can then use `left/right-arrow` to position the cursor. By default, any characters you type will be inserted at the cursor (you can change this); pressing `INS`ert toggles between insert and overtype mode.

I'll let you guess what `Del` `Home` and `down-arrow` do...

Pressing `enter` will execute the reformed line and replace the history-list pointer to the last command entered (ie. the reformed line)

Comment: Why is `Home` special here? I mean, it works on the command line similar to how it would work in a text editor, and so if you've mentioned `Home`, why not mention `End` as well? Or did you, perhaps, mean a different button (with a different function)?

Comment: It does edit the current command but doesn't modify/remove it from history. The incorrect (typo) still remains in history, if we press F8 >1 the incorrect one shows up. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>F8</kbd> multiple times till you reach the correct command, or press <kbd>F7</kbd> to select the command easily.

You can completely clear command history using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, but cannot selectively delete a single command.